# kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException File not founded, only in samsung devices

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

I used this method to get file from uri, it is work fine with all devices but only crash with samsung devices!

```
fun Activity.getFilePath(uri: Uri): File {
    var cursor: Cursor? = null
    return try {
        val dataArray = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
        cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, dataArray, null, null, null)
        val index = cursor?.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
        cursor?.moveToFirst()
        File(index?.let { cursor?.getString(it) })
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        throw KotlinNullPointerException("File not founded")
    } finally {
        cursor?.close()
    }
}
```

**get image from gallery**

```
 fun Activity.chooseImageFromGallery(withAskPermission: Boolean) {
    if (isPermissionsGranted(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST)
    } else {
        if (withAskPermission && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                    PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST)
        }
    }
}
```

**on Activity result**

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST) {
        uri = data?.data
        file = uri?.let { activity?.getFilePath(it) }
        //
    } 
}
```

Comment: "it is work fine with all devices" -- no, it does not. For example, it will not work on Android Q and higher devices, where `DATA` is no longer accessible. At best, your code might work on some older devices if the `Uri` explicitly came from the `MediaStore`. In general, a `Uri` does not have to point to a file, let alone a file that you can access via the filesystem.

Comment: I updated my question and added gallery method and how i handle on activity result

Comment: There is no requirement for `DATA` to contain a filesystem path that you can use. And, in a few months, millions of devices will be running Android 10 (formerly Android Q) where you cannot access `DATA` anyway. So, I recommend that you stop using `DATA` and just work with the `Uri`.

Comment: @CommonsWare okay, thanks